# Why I am getting connection error between Azure Redis and spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, azure-redis-cache

I want to connect to Azure Redis from you spring boot application. But I am getting connections error `io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot obtain initial Redis Cluster topology` and if I see detailed message I can see `Cannot retrieve cluster partitions from [rediss://********************************************@myurl.redis.cache.windows.net:6380?timeout=3s]`

I followed following codes to establish the connection.

In pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then in the application yml.

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
  redis:
    ssl: false
    host: qortex-platform-dev-backoffice-portal.redis.cache.windows.net
    port: 6380
    password: 8RP9lcB7fbiX0ceCwNyF8dOe9pJ33w6YbAzCa
```

Configuration is like.

```
@Bean
    public RedisClusterConfiguration defaultRedisConfig() {
        RedisClusterConfiguration configuration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
        configuration.addClusterNode(new RedisNode("myurl.redis.cache.windows.net",6380));
        configuration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisPassword));
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration defaultRedisConfig) {
        ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofMinutes(10L))
                .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers()
                .build();

        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .useSsl().and()
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
                .clientOptions(ClusterClientOptions.builder().topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions).build())
                .build();

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(defaultRedisConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, SessionPayload> template(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, SessionPayload> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

In the logic.

```
SessionPayload sessionPayloadFetched = (SessionPayload) template.opsForHash().get(HASH_KEY, sessionPayload.getUserId());
```

Why I am getting this error?.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have installed Redis Cluster locally in your machine.

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make //The binaries that are now compiled are available in the src directory
$ src/redis-server
```

This should solve the error.

Comment: Why should I set up redis cluster locally as this is remote hosted redis.?